# Is there a way to make MySQL query behavior different depending on values of arguments?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, search

I am working on project with search functionality and I am trying to make particular search with single MySQL query. 
Problem I have is that some of query parameters are not obligatory so they can be null. 
Is there a way to make MySQL query that "ignores" its own parts if some parameter is null? I would like to avoid writing procedures in DB.
We are using Spring Boot with JPA.

I could't find any solutions on web, if this is duplicate in anyway reference that question.

In this simple example I would like to know if it is possible to make query in such a way that comparison between ownerName (?2) and nested select can return TRUE if ownerName is NULL.

```
@Query(
    value= "SELECT * FROM car WHERE car.name = ?1 
       AND ?2 = (SELECT person.name FROM person WHERE person.id = car.owner_id)",
    nativeQuery = true)  
List<Car> findCarsByNameAndOwnerName(String carName, String ownerName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make this work by applying a `OR <parameter> IS NULL` predicate. For example, to make both parameters optional, you can do like this:

```
@Query(
value= "SELECT * FROM car WHERE (car.name = ?1 OR ?1 IS NULL)
   AND (?2 = (SELECT person.name FROM person WHERE person.id = car.owner_id) OR ?2 IS NULL)",
nativeQuery = true)  
List<Car> findCarsByNameAndOwnerName(String carName, String ownerName);
```